# DICOM why need overlay and how to read it

Tags: dicom

[image]Just wondering why we need the **overlay** and when we will need it?

I have a **Scout** image with overlay, what do these **dots** mean and what do these numbers or **fractions** mean?

How these numbers are drawn on the image?

Comment: It is hard to answer your question. I even do not know if it relates to overlays in general, to a particular overlay, to programming DICOM file visualization or what else. E.g. "how these numbers are drawn on the image?". Which numbers? Does the question refer to where the information comes from or how it is interpreted in renderning? Sharing the image would be helpful as well

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry to go to another event and forgot the image. I just added it in.

Answer (score 6):

DICOM standard allows two specific types of overlays (graphics and ROI) along with the image and overlays are stored as 1-bit image in Overlay Data (60XX, 0050) attribute. A dataset can have up to 16 separate overpay planes (using the repeating groups encoding).

The overlay plane that represents region of interest (ROI) will have value of “R” for Overlay Type (60xx, 0040) attribute and ROI Area (60xx, 1301), ROI Mean (60xx,1302) and ROI Standard Deviation (60xx, 1303) can be used for the corresponding values of ROI. All bits representing ROI will have a value of 1 that represents the pixels under the boundaries of the actual image data.

Graphic Overlay will have value of “G” in Overlay Type (60xx, 0040) attribute and it is used for expressing reference marks (reference line), graphic annotation, or bitmap text etc.  Again, all visible values in an overlay plane are set to 1.

The Overlay Rows (60xx, 0010) and Overlay Columns (60xx,0011) specifies the width and height of the overlay plane. Overlay Bits Allocated is always 1 and Overlay Bit Position is 0 (it was used in previous version and usage has been retired). Overlay Origin (60xx, 0050) is used to described the first overlay point with respect to the pixel in the image and 1\1 represents upper left pixel of the image.

Answer (score 3):

Overlays can be used to display any data over an image. You could, for example, allow users to make annotations or graphics marks. You cannot mark the original data, so the overlay is stored in a separate layer.

In your case, the creator of the overlay should explain its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the overlay is:
i.e. 2/16 -> Series number 2 and slice number 16